# Running Dism.exe CleanupImage takes ages and eventually ends up with an error

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-update

On Wednesday evening I launched on my Windows Server 2016 Diskm.exe as this "dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup".
I thought it would be a straightforward process but when I checked it out on Thursday morning it was stuck at 70.4% and TiWorker.exe still working (and eating up a lot of CPU).

[image]

I checked it out several times in the morning and it always was showing the same value. In the afternoon I was about to kill the process when I saw it had reached 100% but was still not finished, just showing 100%. Today Friday I checked it out and this time the process did finish but was showing the error shown below. I downloaded the log file [here](https://www.corobori.com/sos/dism.log) but I don't have the knowledge to understand it.

From what I see the WinSXS temp folder space was reduced to 132 Mb versus the 6Gb I had before but I am still worried about this error. Is there anybody around able to understand the dism log file and let me know if anything is wrong that I could fix up somehow.

[image]